# Red5 RTMP Streaming

Tags: java, flash, red5, rtmp

I'm very new to RTMP streaming and am seeking help. Just enough to get me started.

I have been Googling for about 5-7 hours now and still cannot determine my answer!

**The documentation of Red5 is limited and cannot find any support at all! Even similar questions to mine are unanswered on stackoverflow :(**

*My questions are:*

1. Why can't I simply place an .mp3
   inside red5's server root and play
   it?
2. To serve a simple MP3 file over
   RTMP. Do I need to write a Java
   application?
3. If so, any pointers?

To make matters worse, I have little to none Java experience.

Please help ST.

Comment: When looking for answers and not finding them here or via google, I suggest joining the projects users list and simultaneously posting your query there.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do what you want to is to install the oflaDemo. Start your red5 server and go to http://localhost:5080/installer

You need to select "oflaDemo" there and install it, if you don't already have it installed. Next place your mp3's or whatever in the following location

```
%RED5_HOME%/webapps/oflaDemo/streams
```

Red5 home will be the directory where you installed Red5. So if you used an installer it may look like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Red5\webapps\oflaDemo\streams
```

To play your mp3 without writing any code flash or java, next go to this url:
http://localhost:5080/demos/ofla_demo.html

Connect and select your file from the list and thats it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also playing with red5, and I've considered these two resources very helpful:

- http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials:Getting_Started_With_Red5_Server
- http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/UsersReferenceManual/Red5CoreTechnologies/01-Creating-New-Applications#Chapter1.CreatenewapplicationsinRed5

Answer (score 0):

for streaming an mp3 file you don't need any functionality of the red5 server, a webserver should be enough.

if you still have to load it from the red5 server:

- is the file accessible in your browser? e.g. http://[red5-server]/file.mp3
- then just use this url when loading the mp3 file in flash as this is not working i want to include url in my jsp how can i do that and what player i have to use

Comment: I have chosen Red5 specifically. I know of the HTTP method and have been using it for more then 2 years.

I really need to use RTMP because of copyright concerns etc.

However I need the content to be loaded over RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

have you got the Demos that come with RED5 installed? You won't have to code in java but you will have to open up a connection in flash in order to stream the mp3, the demos that comes with RED5 installation should have those examples.

Answer (score 0):

I felt Wowza easier. There is a free version of Wowza which allows upto 10 connections. But after that you have start shelling money. But definitely lesser than FMS! And it is very easy. Just a few steps to setup and you can have your very own RTMP application streaming mp3 :) And if you do find the answer of how to stream RTMP on Red5, please do let me know!